# Bipolar transistor with resistor from base to collector

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, gain

I am given the following circuit.
B = 100, Va = infinite (ro = 0).

[image]

I am supposed to find the polarization of the circuit, but i am told to not ignore Ib. I also have to find the gain: vo/vi.

I'm little confused on how to start this, because of the Rf resistor, and the fact that ib is not equal to zero.

Is ic divided into the collector of the transistor and to Rf?

I made this schematic to represent the circuit in DC mode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy62gV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: In a steady state, would current ever flow out of the base through the resistor to the collector?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I would say yes since there is base current: Ib =Ic/B

Comment: What does that tell you about Vcb?

Comment: You're saying that _conventional_ current is flowing _out of_ both of the base and collector?

Comment: Suggestion: start from putting arrows representing the currents for the device alone. You can choose your own convention, but I suggest you show Ic and Ib *entering* the NPN transistor, while Ie will be exiting it. Then, to reduce the number of unknowns express Ib and Ie in terms of Ic. Now you have three unknowns: Ic, Vce and Vbe (and the last one can be set to a certain value). Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN DC:

[image]

At node \$V_C\$, applying KCL gives:

$$ 
I_X = I_B + I_C 
$$
or
$$
\begin{align} 
I_X &= I_B + \beta I_B = (\beta + 1)I_B = I_E
\end{align}
$$
(it is evident that \$I_X = I_E\$)

Now we apply Kirchhoff voltage law
$$ V_{CC} - R_C I_E - R_F I_B - V_{BE} - R_E I_E = 0 $$

$$V_{CC} - R_C (\beta + 1) I_B - R_F I_B - V_{BE} - R_E (\beta + 1) I_B = 0$$

$$ I_B = \frac{V_{CC} - V_{BE}}{R_F + (\beta + 1)(R_C + R_E)}  $$

Once \$ I_B\$ is obtained you can easily find \$ I_C, I_E \$ and \$ V_C\$
$$ I_C = \beta I_B = \frac{\beta(V_{CC} - V_{BE})}{R_F + (\beta + 1)(R_C + R_E)} $$

$$ I_E = (\beta + 1) I_B = \frac{(\beta + 1)(V_{CC} - V_{BE})}{R_F + (\beta + 1)(R_C + R_E)} $$

To obtain \$V_C\$ we apply the KVL over \$ V_{CC}\$ and \$ R_C \$

$$V_{CC} - R_C I_E - V_C = 0$$
$$V_C = V_{CC} - R_C (\beta + 1)I_B$$

In AC:

[image]

$$ r_\pi = \frac{V_T}{I_B} $$
and

$$ V_{out} = -i_c R_C $$

We apply KCL over \$v_{out}\$ node

$$ i_f + i_c = \beta i_b $$

solve for \$i_c\$

$$ i_c = \beta i_b - i_f $$

and

$$ v_{out} = -(\beta i_b - i_f)R_C $$

where

$$ i_f = \frac{V_{in} - V_{out}}{R_F} $$

we have

$$ v_{out} = -\left(\beta i_b - \frac{V_{in} - V_{out}}{R_F}\right)R_C $$

or

$$ v_{out} = \frac{-\beta i_b R_C + \frac{R_C}{R_F}v_{in}}{1 + \frac{R_C}{R_F}} $$

We apply KVL over left mesh

$$ v_{in} - r_\pi i_b - R_E (\beta + 1) i_b = 0 $$

or

$$ i_b = \frac{v_{in}}{r_\pi + R_E (\beta + 1)} $$

Therefore
$$ v_{out} = \frac{-\beta \frac{v_{in}}{r_\pi + R_E (\beta + 1)} R_C + \frac{R_C}{R_F}v_{in}}{1 + \frac{R_C}{R_F}} $$

or

$$ \frac{v_{out}}{v_{in}} = \frac{ \frac{-\beta R_C}{r_\pi + R_E (\beta + 1)} + \frac{R_C}{R_F} }{1 + \frac{R_C}{R_F} } $$